# cannot connect to mysql in ubuntu

Tags: mysql

Hello i have this error when i tried to connect mysql in terminal, what should i do please ?

```
thomas@thomas-Latitude-E6440:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
thomas@thomas-Latitude-E6440:~$ /etc/init.d/mysql  stop
Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
thomas@thomas-Latitude-E6440:~$ /etc/init.d/mysql  start
Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

Comment: Well, what does `systemctl status mysql.service` or `journalctl -xe` say?

Comment: ```● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-07-10 14:58:33 CEST; 2min 17s ago
    Process: 6428 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)```

Comment: ```juil. 10 14:58:33 thomas-Latitude-E6440 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
juil. 10 14:58:33 thomas-Latitude-E6440 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
juil. 10 14:58:33 thomas-Latitude-E6440 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
juil. 10 14:58:33 thomas-Latitude-E6440 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
juil. 10 14:58:33 thomas-Latitude-E6440 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.```

Comment: Add these information to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: ```The job identifier is 3007 and the job result is done.
juil. 10 14:58:33 thomas-Latitude-E6440 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
juil. 10 14:58:33 thomas-Latitude-E6440 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support```

Answer (score 1):

Try to start your mysql service:

```
sudo systemctl start mysql or sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

If it fails, try installing mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If it still fails then to do a complete reinstallation of mysql services:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: after start mysql service ```The job identifier is 3007 and the job result is done.
juil. 10 14:58:33 thomas-Latitude-E6440 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
juil. 10 14:58:33 thomas-Latitude-E6440 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support```

Comment: after install mysql server: ```mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.```

Comment: after get remove it's abort when say yes ? 
```The following packages will be REMOVED: colord* gnome-control-center* libmysqlclient21* libsane* libsnmp35* mysql-client-8.0* mysql-client-core-8.0* mysql-common* mysql-server* mysql-server-8.0* mysql-server-core-8.0* mysql-workbench-community* sane-utils* 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 13 to remove and 10 not upgraded. After this operation, 387 MB disk space will be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Abor```